# Axios.All (chaining multiple requests together) not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

EDIT: I resolved it. The issue was that I was passing the userData object to something else that didn't require all of it. When I narrowed it down I got what I was hoping to achieve.

So I'm trying to make it so that when a user registers on my web app, it'll automatically log them in and then redirect to the home page. The redirect to home page is working, but it's not registering the user or setting the user's details. I've looked at the documentation and believe I'm doing it correctly, but still no results?

authActions.js File:

```js
// Register User
export const registerUser = (userData, history) => dispatch => {
    axios.post('/users/register', userData)
        //.then(res => history.push('/login'))
        .catch(err => 
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ERRORS,
                payload: err.response.data
            })    
        );
}

// Login - Get User Token
export const loginUser = (userData) => dispatch => {
    axios.post('/users/login', userData)
        .then(res => {
            // Save to localStorage
            const { token } = res.data;
            // Set token to LocalStorage
            localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
            // Set token to Auth header
            setAuthToken(token);
            // Decode token to get user data
            const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
            // Set current user
            dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
        })
        .catch(err => 
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ERRORS,
                payload: err.response.data
            }) 
        );
}

// Set logged in user
export const setCurrentUser = (decoded) => {
    return {
        type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
        payload: decoded
    }
} 



// Register, Login, Set User all at the same time
export const regLogSetUser = (userData, history) => dispatch => {
    axios.all([registerUser(), loginUser(), setCurrentUser()])
    .then(res => history.push('/'))
    .catch(err => 
        dispatch({
            type: GET_ERRORS,
            payload: err.response.data
        })    
    );
}
```

In my Register component, I'm also properly calling in the Prop Function (at the bottom) (after importing it at the top).

```js
Register.propTypes = {
    regLogSetUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    auth: state.auth,
    errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { regLogSetUser })(withRouter(Register));
```

Here is the link to the documentation:

https://github.com/axios/axios

And here is what it says for Axios.all()

```js
Performing multiple concurrent requests

function getUserAccount() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345');
}

function getUserPermissions() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345/permissions');
}

axios.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    // Both requests are now complete
  }));
```

Thanks for the help. Still learning!

Comment: What is `dispatch` and why are you using it?

Comment: I'm using dispatch because I'm using redux-thunk

Comment: Well I have to use redux-thunk to dispatch the action to set the current user don't I in the login function I've created? Otherwise how would I set the current user if I remove it? I don't believe it'd work if I removed the dispatch. I just need the axios.all() to run the three in sequential order using the: userData that i'm passing in.

Comment: I'm not familiar with redux-thunk, I cannot say how removing it will affect your application. The method `axios.all` is equivalent to [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). These methods do not sequence the promises, they just wait for all of the promises to resolve. You cannot simply call all of the methods simultaneously, you have to sequence them by waiting for the last action to complete before executing the next action.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. How would you recommend I go about doing that? I tried .then() repeatedly and just put one inside the other but it didn't seem to work properly. Thanks for your help, I'm still new.

Comment: I think the issue is that on my registration page, I'm asking for users to confirm their password and it's getting stuck in the userData. Then when I try to log in with the same userData, it's running the third property of the userData object and realizing it can't make the loginUser request.

Comment: Yup that was the issue. I got it working properly now. Thank you for your assistance!!